# A way to score average just like disjunction_max

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have a query, use dis_max to get the max score from batch documents which scored by several nested queries:

```
{  
  "query":  {
    "dis_max": {
      "queries": [
         {
           "nested" : {}, //nested_1
           "nested" : {}  //nested_2
         }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

And is there a query like "dis_avg", not return the max score, but get the average score.

For example, as I know:

1. nested_1 get score 0.7 from object_a, score 0.2 from object_b,
2. nested_2 get score 0.5 from object_a, score 0.8 from object_b,

and dis_max scores object_b 0.8 and mark it as 1st, and scores object_a 0.7 and mark it as 2nd.

And any query here so that I can:

scores object_b 0.5 and mark is as 2nd, and scores object_a 0.6 and mark it as 1st.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used bool query to combine several queries and use boost to average weight each query to get average score.